# Trying to make a Lua Script for Logitech Not Sure How

Tags: lua, autohotkey, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have this code I made for "AHK" however I want this in LOGITECH GHUB .Lua for the scripting tab, so I can use it as on board memory.

```
MButton::
Send {WheelDown}
sleep 50
Send {WheelDown}
sleep 50
Send {WheelUp}
return
```

I did this with macros section in ghub but it doesn't work when mouse is in on board memory mode, how can I make this ahk script in .lua scripting for logitech g hub.

Comment: Try to create a macro as usual (GHub will remember the sequence of your actions and will save it as macro).

Comment: Lua script does not work when mouse is in on board memory mode.  Only simple macros (sequences of key press/release and delays) are available in this mode.  For Lua script to work, a Lua virtual machine should be running, it is a part of Logitech Mouse Driver.